# Cannot run java class from command line

Tags: java, javac

I created a package in Eclipse and ran my HelloWorld just fine from Eclipse.

When I went to a command prompt and navigated to that folder and ran javac HelloWorld.java, it compilied without issue.

When I ran java HelloWorld, I got 
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

I also tried java Hello.HelloWorld thinking that it might be because it had a package declaration

```
package Hello; 
public class HelloWorld { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       System.out.println("Hi there. How you doin?");
   } 
}
```

Comment: Add the code to your question. Without it, it's hard to know if you have a package declaration, and if you have a proper `main`.

Comment: From which location you tried to run your command and what is structure of your classes?

Comment: OH!! I think I've got it.  When I declare package Hello; java looks for a folder named Hello under the current folder.

Comment: package Hello;

public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hi there.  How you doin?");

 }

}

Comment: Have you read this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/139985

Comment: How do I format this as code?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If I navigate to the folder where the class file is and run java from there, shouldn't it find the class right there in that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `javac`, use the switch `-d` to specify that you would like to create the folder structure for package. [javac reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

E.g. `javac -d . HelloWorld.java`

When you say `-d .`, compiler creates the classes with package directory structure in the current path.

Once you have the compiled classes, use `java Hello.HelloWorld` to run the program.

Suggests you to start the package name with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the code outside the Hello folder

```
java Hello/HelloWorld
```

You should have `HelloWorld.class` inside Hello directory.

Comment: Thanks all!!! I realized I had to first create the classes folder in Windows before running the -d switch.

I also was running java from within the folder where the class was.  Going up a folder and giving it the relative path did the trick! 

Thanks again! @rvillablanca